# Content-based recommender system in R

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, data-science

I am trying to build a basic content-based recommender engine based on movie genres, the data set is from MovieLens. Now I want to Simulate the real situation. If I build a new website, and have new users and items(movies) that I want to recommend to them, I am not sure what users' taste are. A cold start problem. My thought is to set the movies genres as categories, like comedy, thriller, etc. Now I just want to randomly recommend any type of movies to users and see if they are interested in specific kind of movie. In next step, how do I randomly recommend these movies to my uses? And how do I know the feedback is precise and positive? Thanks in advance

Here's the code I learn:

```
library(tidyr)
library(recommenderlab)
library(magrittr)
library(readxl)
setwd("C:\\xxxx")
movies <- read.csv("movies.csv", header = TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ratings <- read.csv("ratings.csv", header = TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
genres <- as.data.frame(movies$genres, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(data.table)
genres2 <- as.data.frame(tstrsplit(genres[,1], '[|]', type.convert=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(genres2) <- c(1:10)

genre_list <- c("Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Crime","Documentary", "Drama", "Fantasy","Film-Noir", "Horror", "Musical", "Mystery","Romance","Sci-Fi", "Thriller", "War", "Western")

genre_matrix <- matrix(0,9126,18) 
genre_matrix[1,] <- genre_list 
colnames(genre_matrix) <- genre_list 
#iterate through matrix
for (i in 1:nrow(genres2)) {
  for (c in 1:ncol(genres2)) {
    genmat_col = which(genre_matrix[1,] == genres2[i,c])
    genre_matrix[i+1,genmat_col] <- 1
  }
}

#convert into dataframe
genre_matrix2 <- as.data.frame(genre_matrix[-1,], stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
for (c in 1:ncol(genre_matrix2)) {
  genre_matrix2[,c] <- as.integer(genre_matrix2[,c])
}
```

Output:

The first movie belongs to Adventure, Animation, Children and Comedy categories

```
     Action Adventure Animation Children Comedy Crime Documentary Drama
1         0         1         1        1      1     0           0     0
2         0         1         0        1      0     0           0     0
3         0         0         0        0      1     0           0     0
4         0         0         0        0      1     0           0     1
5         0         0         0        0      1     0           0     0
6         1         0         0        0      0     1           0     0
7         0         0         0        0      1     0           0     0
8         0         1         0        1      0     0           0     0
9         1         0         0        0      0     0           0     0
10        1         1         0        0      0     0           0     0
11        0         0         0        0      1     0           0     1
12        0         0         0        0      1     0           0     0
13        0         1         1        1      0     0           0     0
14        0         0         0        0      0     0           0     1
```

Comment: In the next step you don't randomly recommend the movies. From your previous recommendations if they clicked certain movies or if they searched a particular movie and watched it, try to capture the several attributes of that movie like actor, director, genre etc and calculate the similarity between the **watched movie** and other movies based on these attributes.

Comment: Initially, you mentioned to have recommended them movies at random...right? It's a good choice to recommend popular movies initially.

Comment: @tushaR I actually haven't recommended yet. Let me get it more clear: Now I have lists of my movies => I tagged every movie with their movie genres => (maybe I need to do the clustering here? since some movies belong to more than one genres) => now new users starting using my website => next step(is it possible that I can randomly select movies from different genres and recommend to users? to see what genres they like. Or should I just wait until they browse the whole lists of movies, click, watch and favorite some of them, then analyze it?)  I am a bit confused here.

Comment: @tushaR yeah! I thought of it too :) But if all my lists of movies are new, then it won't be able to work since we are not sure whether it's popular or not.

Comment: In that case, it's better to wait and let some data accumulate ;)